# `VideoView.start()` cause other views to break

Tags: android-layout, android

When my activity receives a new intent via `onNewIntent`, it updates the data of three `View`s, an `ImageView`, a `TextView`, and a `VideoView`. The problem is, the two other views just flash, then disappear when my `VideoView` comes on. After scattering a few breakpoints, I discovered that they appear when their content is set, but disappear when `VideoView.onStart()` is called in my `MediaPlayer.onPrepared()` method. I also have an `AlertDialog` show up when the menu button is pressed. After pressing the menu button, it shows up. I'm on Android API 9, as this is the API on the device I'm working on. I really need help, so I'd appreciate any advice.

Here's the layout. I don't think it's the issue though:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marquee"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/marquee"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/marquee"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Take note that the `TextView` is meant to be a marquee; it's supposed to keep scrolling sideways, until it is disposed of. I discovered that when the text is too short for it to start the marquee, the TextView AND the ImageView disappear (as stated earlier, they appear for a split second, then disappear). **However, when the text causes the marquee feature to activate, everything works.**

**CURRENTLY:**

I got it to work by calling `postInvalidateDelayed(500)` on my `ImageView` and `TextView` after calling `VideoView.start()`. I think the `start()` method is causing the problem, and requires that other views call `invalidate()`. Also, for some reason, there needs to be a small delay in-between the call to `start()` and the call to `invalidate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a method, but it seems very bad:

```
private void startVideo() {
    this.videoView.start();
    if (this.imageView != null)
        this.imageView.postInvalidateDelay(500);
    if (this.textView != null)
        this.textView.postInvalidateDelay(500);
}
```

It works, but it makes me feel dirty.

Answer (score 0):

The layout is the issue.

Your VideoView is declared as `match_parent, match_parent`, allowing it to consume the whole width and height of the screen. Since you declared it last on the xml file (You used RelativeLayout. Ordering matters), the TextView and the ImageView would be covered by the VideoView.

If you're confused,
`match_parent` is basically the same as `fill_parent`. It's just another name for `fill_parent` in android 2.3+

Now what can you do about it?

Reorder your views in such a way that the largest is declared first. In this case, VideoView, then ImageView, then TextView.

Also note that your ImageView has height set to `fill_parent` - you may not want that.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Also, wouldn't the `TextView` have to come first since the `ImageView` and `VideoView` depend on them?